# C# MSchart X-Axis divide line

Tags: c#-4.0, mschart

I would like to add divede line in chart as below.
The Type of X-axis is DateTime.

How can I do this?

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lUSnG.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO, please be a bit more specific when asking question: what have you tried, what do you expect, etc. See [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

It is to change the x axis to DateTime.
Change XValueType and LabelStyle .

```
 chart1.Series[0].XValueType = ChartValueType.DateTime;
            chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.LabelStyle.Format = "hh:mm:ss";
            chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.IntervalType = DateTimeIntervalType.Seconds;
    DateTime minDate = baseData.AddSeconds(-59);
            DateTime maxDate = baseData;
            chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Minimum = minDate.ToOADate();
            chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Maximum = maxDate.ToOADate();
```